# Opening offline cube from another machine

Tags: excel, ssas, offline, cube

Here is the steps to my problem:

1. I have a MOLAP cube with MOLAP dimensions on the AS2008 server
2. I connect to it with Excel 2007 and save it in a local cube file (.cub)
3. I disconnect from network, then I try to open the offline cub file through excel. It is successful.
4. I copy the .cub file to another machine, start Excel, try to connect to the .cub and I got error.

Please help. Thank you so much.

Additional info, on the machine I failed to open the offline cube, I have also installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services 10.0 OLE DB Provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great job finding a solution! I don't think you should necessarily need to put the local cube in the same folder, or have the same localization settings. Another possibility: Was the local cube in use at the time you copied it? If so, the file can be affected. Try copying the local cube when it is not in use and see if it can be used elsewhere.

Regards,

Nathan Peterson

www.cubeslice.com

Comment: Amazing grace, I was blind, you right! If only you nudged me earlier... Duh! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the solution. We must establish at least these 2 conventions **between source and target machine when saving the cube**:

1. Same drive letter and folder name, e.g.: C:\Cube\Test.cub.
2. Same Localization in the Control Panel Regional setting.